# Electronic signature in France

Tags: france, signature

In France, the [Article 1316-3](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCodeArticle.do;jsessionid=5B0206551AF6FEF74B4972BECAD58213.tpdila13v_1?idArticle=LEGIARTI000006437828&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070721&dateTexte=20060406) ([mirror](http://archive.is/KhozE)) created by Law n°2000-230 on March 13, 2000 - art. 3 JORF March 14 2000 says that:

> "L'écrit sur support électronique a la même force probante que l'écrit sur support papier."

which can be translated as:

> "Writing on electronic media has the same evidential value as written on paper."

Does this mean that if some legal entity ( e.g., a bank ) asks me to fill up, sign, and return by snail mail a form they sent to me by email, I can instead email  them the completed and signed form, and the legal entity is legally forced to accept it (i.e., they cannot ask me for snail mail)?

Answer (score 2):

"Same evidential value" doesn't mean that the person making an offer can't place stricter conditions on how you can indicate acceptance of an offer.

That is, sure, they *could* take your electronic signature and use it as  strong evidence in court. But they *want* a physical, pen-on-paper signature.